# Fitting mixtures of truncated normal distributions in R

Tags: r, mixture-model, gaussian-mixture-model

I am trying detect the number of modes in a variable in R.

My variable was collected in a survey on a 1-7 scale which is why I want to fit mixtures of truncated Gaussian distributions.
I am struggling to find a way to do so in R.

Here is an code to produce an example of a simulated mixture of three truncated normal distributions:

```
#install.packages("truncnorm")
library(truncnorm)

set.seed(123)

# Simulate the first truncated normal distribution
mu1 <- 0.5; sd1 <- 0.5
a1 <- 0; b1 <- 7 # upper and lower bounds
N1 <- 100
sample1 <- rtruncnorm(N1, a=a1, b=b1, mean=mu1, sd=sd1)

# Simulate the second truncated normal distribution
mu2 <- 5; sd2 <- 1.5
a2 <- 0; b2 <- 7
N2 <- 110
sample2 <- rtruncnorm(N2, a=a2, b=b2, mean=mu2, sd=sd2)

# Simulate third truncated normal distribution
mu3 <- 6.8; sd3 <- 0.5
a3 <- 0; b3 <- 7
N3 <- 60
sample3 <- rtruncnorm(N3, a=a3, b=b3, mean=mu3, sd=sd3)

# Merge the two samples
combined_sample <- c(sample1, sample2, sample3)
data <- data.frame(combined_sample, 
                   class = c(rep("sample1", N1), rep("sample2", N2), rep("sample3", N3))) # true class

# Plot the joined distribution for illustration
hist(data$combined_sample, breaks=30, main="Merged Truncated Normal Distributions", 
     xlab="Value", ylab="Frequency", col="lightblue", border="black")
abline(v=c(mu1, mu2, mu3), col=c("red", "blue", "green"), lwd=2) # Add the true means for reference
```

---

I am unsure how to now recover these three truncated distributions from the data using R (i.e., how to find out how many truncated normals this distribution consists of and what their means and variances are).

For Gaussian mixture models without truncation I usually use the `mclust` package but for some cases of mixtures of truncated data (such as the example simulation above) it does not reliably recover the number of modes:

```
# install.packages("mclust")
library(mclust)

# model with lowest BIC has 4 components: 
mclustBIC(data$combined_sample)
```

(Here it overestimates the number of underlying distributions).

Is there a way to account for the truncation of the underlying normal distributions in R?

Comment: Asking for package recommendations here is off topic. Just describe the problem and if a package can help, it will be suggested. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If the question is more about what statistical method is appropriate for this analysis or checking formulas, you would get better help at [stats.se]

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing this out! I added a reproducible example and adjusted my question, hope this makes it easier to answer and more appropriate for this forum.